# Get data from WebApi in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have webapi and her method:

```
[HttpPost, HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetData")]
public MyData GetData([FromUri] MyData data)
{
  return datamanager.get(data);
}
```

How do I invoke this method? I.e. how do I send `data` parameter through query part of URL?

To invoke get method which takes no parameters I use following code:

```
public static async Task<myClassl> GetData()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://sasa.com");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/GetData");
    myClassl data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<myClassl>();

    return data ;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseApiAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseApiAddress"];
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseApiAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response=client.GetAsync("/api/GetData",data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var mydata = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyData>().Result;
}
else
{
Debug.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: When I use GetAsync I hace error in compilation, when i use PostAsync in webapi i have null parameter

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell to add the next lines of code inside your App.config file inside configuration (localhost:23602 is just an example use your port)
<appSettings>
    <add key="baseApiAddress" value="http://localhost:23602/"/>
  </appSettings>

Comment: i am getting error: Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(string, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: GetAsync does not have a data param; most probably the params must be sent in URI