# C# - Align Text Dynamically With Code

Tags: c#, winforms

How could I align text dynamically to other controls?

I want to align texts under picture boxes:

[image]

EDIT: Here is my code: http://pasted.co/6347d9e4 but i didnt have any code, i coded these recently, and i dont understand why i get -6 ? (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Take a look at the TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: You could wrap it into a `Button` is has the Property `TextImageRelation` where you can handle things like that.

Comment: @diiN_  I didn't try anything because i can't :\

Comment: @Nudity Thanks but i dont wanna delete and replace all that thing, isn't there a way with code?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz can you provide some of you code ?

Comment: @Nudity http://pasted.co/e289313b

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz may I recommend you using the RiotGamesAPI[ https://developer.riotgames.com/ ] so you don't need to process the championnames manually.

Comment: @Nudity Thanks, i'm trying that now!

Comment: @Nudity It's not for C# I think

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz its just a simple WebApi you do `HttpWebRequests` i.e. `/api/lol/{region}/v1.2/champion` to get all chamption data. `{region}` shall then be replaced with your region (euw, na, whatever) This returns a JSON (this can be converted to a .Net class (=> http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can get it also with `NuGet`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15211161/4610605 to see how to get the data. Then parse the JSON to c#.

Comment: @Nudity /api/lol/tr/v1.2/champion does not work. Could you send me the full uri?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz you need an API-Key. You get one for free when u register at https://developer.riotgames.com/ Then once you're logged in you can simulate requests here: https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1077/3717 and see what you get back from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a quick and dirty example on how to get this done:

**The UserControl:**

```
public partial class ImageWithText : UserControl
{
    public ImageWithText(Image image = null, string champName = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(image != null)
        {
            ChampionImage.Image = image;
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(champName))
        {
            ChamptionName.Text = champName;
        }
    }

    private void ImageWithText_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the Width of the usercontrol:
        int ucWidth = this.Width;
        int centerPoint = ucWidth / 2;

        //Place text in the center:
        int labelWidth = ChamptionName.Width;
        int labelCenter = labelWidth / 2;
        //Set the lable to the centerPoint and then shift half of the lable to the left!
        //We leave the Top value untouched since we only want to set the HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT
        ChamptionName.Left = centerPoint - labelCenter;
    }

    public void SetChampionImage(Image image)
    {
        ChampionImage.Image = image;
        ChampionImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public void SetChampionName(string name)
    {
        ChamptionName.Text = name;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

**The Designer Code:**

```
partial class ImageWithText
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ChampionImage = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.ChamptionName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ChampionImage)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // ChampionImage
        // 
        this.ChampionImage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
        this.ChampionImage.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
        this.ChampionImage.Name = "ChampionImage";
        this.ChampionImage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 120);
        this.ChampionImage.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.ChampionImage.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ChampionImage.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.ChamptionName.AutoSize = true;
        this.ChamptionName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.ChamptionName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 130);
        this.ChamptionName.Name = "label1";
        this.ChamptionName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(73, 13);
        this.ChamptionName.TabIndex = 1;
        this.ChamptionName.Text = "SampleText";
        // 
        // ImageWithText
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.Controls.Add(this.ChamptionName);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ChampionImage);
        this.Name = "ImageWithText";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 150);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ImageWithText_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ChampionImage)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ChampionImage;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label ChamptionName;
```

---

So when I apply this on a Window:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Create new Instance of UserControl:
        //Simple:
        ImageWithText champion = new ImageWithText();
        //Advanced (pass parameters in construcor):
        ImageWithText champion = new ImageWithText(Properties.Resources.Ashe, "Ashe");
        //Set Image and Name (if not set in constructor:)
        champion.SetChampionName("Ashe");
        champion.SetChampionImage(Properties.Resources.Ashe);
        //Add to Window:
        this.Controls.Add(chamption);
    }       
}
```

I get this result:

### [image]

**Riot Games API:**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.2/champion?api_key=<YourApiKey>");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
ChampionList list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionList>(responseString);
```

use the class below: (from http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Champion
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public bool active { get; set; }
     public bool botEnabled { get; set; }
     public bool freeToPlay { get; set; }
     public bool botMmEnabled { get; set; }
     public bool rankedPlayEnabled { get; set; }
}
public class ChampionList
{
     public List<Champion> champions { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**
For me it is working.
I stored the reponse you got in a file.

[image]

Comment: That's what i've always wanted! Thank you!!

Comment: Np mate. We're here to help !

Comment: I've noticed that riot api method is better but;                                       http://pasted.co/48621837                                                                                     code won't work: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz this is because you are converting the output to <string>. Use http://json2csharp.com/ to get a class form the responses you get and then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>`to get it there. Note I recommend not to pose your apikey online :P next time better hide it ^^ it can be seen in the url in your code :D

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz see my edit above !

Comment: lol :D and i tried that method but it gives an error like this :  {. Path '', line 1, position 1

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz can you please specify the error more detailed ? Is it an exception ? if so what kind ? so its at the line where you convert ?

Comment: Its an exception: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1                                                        Yes, its at the line where i convert

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz see my edit !

Comment: Why can't i get static champion's list? http://pasted.co/8ee37925

Answer (score 2):

If it is necessary to group picture and text together I would create user control by combining PictureBox and Label. Text alignment can be implemented inside the control. Each TableLayoutPanel cell can be populated by this user control.

Comment: And then for each control created, you can set the Picture source and text. I wouldn't recommend TableLayoutPanel for the control though. I would recommend using a label capable of wrapping the text to fit.

Comment: Thanks for help! But i have to replace all that picture boxes, isn't there any way with code?

Comment: I made a usercontrol but i cant still align though :\